# How can i convert existing Ruby built application to maven project?

Tags: maven, jruby

I am working on Ruby application, now I want to build my application using maven tool, please provide pointers how can I convert my exiting application to maven project

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to use maven over the existing ruby build tools like rake and bundler.

If you are using JRuby you may want to look at the torquebox maven plugins:

https://github.com/torquebox/jruby-maven-plugins